# Netflix Addon for Kodi/OSMC

Tags: pi-3, kodi, streaming-video, osmc

I am using my RaspberryPi 3 for a wile now. I've looked all over the internets if there is any proper Netflix video addon to use. However, most of the addons I came across did not work. The most promising addon was the `NetfliXBMC` addon. However, even after [updating the Chromelauncher and disabling the Kiosk-mode](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201510/page05.html) it did not show anything.

So, as of **August 2017** I want to ask if there is any *easy to install and use* Netflix addon for Kodi on OSMC, since most of the stuff on the web is a few years old.

Since there have been and still are a lot of blog entries etc. about this which do not provide sufficient solutions, I thought this might be the right thing to ask the Raspi enthusiasts here.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask on the Kodi forums?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a proper Netflix addon but it uses Kodi 17 (krypton)'s newly implemented InputStream API. However, Kodi 17 still isn't enough for running the plugin, Netflix uses DRM encryption which is only supported in the Kodi 18 nightly builds. At the time writing, OSMC is using Kodi 17 wich doesn't support this feature. My sugestion is using raspbian (or other os) and instaling a Kodi 18 nightly build (mainstream will not work). This would need more work than simply installing OSMC but you should have no problems. You can find the plugin in the github page below.

https://github.com/asciidisco/plugin.video.netflix

Comment: Since OSMC in the current stable release does not come with Kodi 18, I will (not yet) mark this Q as solved. Please understand. As soon as OSMC and/or Kodi will be updated and the plugin will run with default OSMC/Kodi, I will let you and other users know. Thanks for the input so far.

Comment: Even if OSMC is updated it won't be updated to the currently nightly builds (obviously). We need to wait until DRM support is pushed to the mainstream.

Comment: Hoping samnazarko will weigh-in here if there is a timeframe to change from Kodi 17 to 18.

Comment: @FFY00  Were you successful in running the Netflix add-on with Kodi18?

Comment: Just an update. OSMC nightly builds now support DRM.

Comment: Well, well, well... With the update to Kodi 18 it works just fine!